# How to use Angular as a widget?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating an application in Angular that will serve as a widget
To create the JS file of the application I am using ng build
This generates the files in the dist/project

How can I embed my widget within the HTML which will be any other technology?
I was thinking of doing it like this...

```
<script>
        (function() {
            
            var scriptComponent = document.createElement("script");
            scriptComponent.type = "text/javascript";
            scriptComponent.src = "path/widget.js";
            scriptComponent.async = true;
            document.head.appendChild(scriptComponent);
        })();
</script>
```

But it doesn't even work. I need help How can I embed my Angular app into another widget-like app? thank you

This works only when i build de JS manually

How can I embed my Angular app into another widget-like app?

Comment: Have you looked for converting angular app to web-component. That could be one solution. A sample blog to achieve this. https://spin.atomicobject.com/2022/10/18/web-component-angular/

Comment: Can I use this alternative also in Angular projects?***

Comment: Yes, the above link os for angular app only. All you need to do is use the `@angular/elements` module and export the app as in the article.
Include the build files in your main code and use the web-component as a html tag.